# Re-calculate height or a UITableViewCell after image is loaded?

Tags: ios, uitableview

guys:

I created table view cell with the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegation method, and now I want to load some photos into the cell and resize the height of the cell to fit those photos, so I think I should do this after the photos are all loaded so that I can get the height to resize the cell.

I know the height of a cell will be calculated within the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegation method, but the   `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method seems to be call before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

so, is there any way to re-calculate the height to resize or re-create the cell after the photos are loaded?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is reload the cell:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

We do that in one of our apps, and it even animates nicely.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what's the better place to do this "reload" action? :)

Comment: When the photos are loaded, you probably have some call back at hand already, i.e. when the download completed - you should be loading images asynchronously anyway. ;) Then cache the image size and reload the cell - heightForRowAtIndexPath: will be called, and you can easily compute the needed cell height there.

Comment: please notice that `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation` breaks the layout sometimes, and it's usually because this method triggers `-setFrame` of a cell. Thus your custom logic, if you have any, in `-setFrame` will be executed multiple times.